# Connect to PostgreSQL in docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose

I'm running a postgres database inside a docker-compose, here's the configuration:

```
  database:
    image: postgis/postgis
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    volumes:
      - /var/lib/postgresql/weav_database:/var/lib/postgresql/data/
    env_file:
      - ./.env/prod.env
```

And here's the env file:

```
POSTGRES_NAME=postgres
POSTGRES_USER=postgres
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
POSTGERS_DB=database
POSTGERS_PORT=5432
POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```

Now when I try to connect to the database, after obv running docker-compose up, through the pgAdmin on my ubuntu server that is the same machine where the docker is running I got and error.

Here's the data I'm using to connect:

```
Host: database (which is the name of docker-compose service, as you can see)
Password: password
Port: 5432
```

If I run `telnet database 5432`
I got `telnet: could not resolve database/5432: Temporary failure in name resolution`

```
telnet localhost 5432
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Unable to connect to remote host
```

How can I solve? I mean how can I connect to docker-compose postgres database from the server where the docker itself is running?

Thank you

Comment: Use `localhost` instead of `database`.

Comment: it doesn't work, I updated the quesiton

Comment: Unless the pgadmin is running inside the same docker (compose) network as the `database` container, it won't be able to resolve that name. As rveerd said, use `localhost:5432` if pgadmin is running on the same server.

Comment: Not sure why you are using `telnet` to connect to a database? Better use `psql` to test connectivity

Comment: Seems like a network problem, can you make sure that the container is listening on port 5432 (running `netstat -ntlp` for example)?

Answer (score 0):

1. Use command line to access PostgreSql docker image:

   `docker-compose exec postgres bash`
2. Run psql (*command-line tool, instead of pgAdmin):

   `psql -U postgres`
3. In psql run command to list all databases:

   `\l`
4. In psql connect to your database using command:

   `\c database`

If All 4 steps successful - issue with pgAdmin connection configuration.